# Content of settings folder of Android app

Tags: java, android

I use following code for work with my android application settings:

```
SharedPreferences pref = activityContext.getSharedPreferences("my_app.cfg", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now I want to enumerate all files in same folder where "my_app.cfg" is located.
How can I get at runtime a full file path to the folder where getSharedPreferences() stores settings files?

Answer (score -1):

```
/data/data/pkgname/shared_prefs/
```

but if u want to use this file in other app , I think it will appear permission problem.

Comment: I understand that package saves prefs in that folder. I do not want to use constant string with path for access to that folder. I thought there are API function that returns that path. Something like that (c#) : var sPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);